# Scrapy Pull Same Data from Multiple Pages

Tags: python, scrapy

This is related to the previous question I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781357/pro-football-reference-team-stats-xpath/38781659#38781659).  I am trying to pull the same data from multiple pages on the same domain.  A small explanation, I'm trying to pull data like offensive yards, turnovers, etc from a bunch of different box scores on a [main page](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2015/games.htm).  Pulling the data from individual pages is working properly as is generation of the urls but when I try to have the spider cycle through all of the pages nothing is returned.  I've looked through many other questions people have asked and the documentation and I can't figure out what is not working. Code is below.  Thanks to anyone who's able to help in advance.

```
import scrapy

from scrapy import Selector
from nflscraper.items import NflscraperItem

class NFLScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pfr"
    allowed_domains = ['www.pro-football-reference.com/']
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2015/games.htm"
        #"http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201510110tam.htm"
    ]

    def parse(self,response):
        for href in response.xpath('//a[contains(text(),"boxscore")]/@href'):
            item = NflscraperItem()
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse_dir_contents(self,response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        # Code to pull out JS comment - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781357/pro-football-reference-team-stats-xpath/38781659#38781659
        extracted_text = response.xpath('//div[@id="all_team_stats"]//comment()').extract()[0]
        new_selector = Selector(text=extracted_text[4:-3].strip())
        # Item population
        item['home_score'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[last()]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['away_score'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[last()]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['home_oyds'] = new_selector.xpath('//*[@id="team_stats"]/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['away_oyds'] = new_selector.xpath('//*[@id="team_stats"]/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['home_dyds'] = item['away_oyds']
        item['away_dyds'] = item['home_oyds']
        item['home_turn'] = new_selector.xpath('//*[@id="team_stats"]/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['away_turn'] = new_selector.xpath('//*[@id="team_stats"]/tbody/tr[8]/td[1]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        yield item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subsequent requests you make *are filtered as offsite*, fix your `allowed_domains` setting:

```
allowed_domains = ['pro-football-reference.com']
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Wow, that's ridiculously annoying.  Nice to know I did things properly otherwise.  Thanks.